# Credit Card Scrubber/Sanitizer library in Java

Tags: java, security, credit-card

I've tried searching to see if something like this exists, but I wasn't able to find anything. I was looking for something that is able to search for credit card numbers and CVV2 codes in a body of text (string), and sanitize/scrub it (replace it with x's for example). I wanted to see if something like this already exists before trying to roll my own (I was going to use the information [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html)).

Comment: Search and replace with a few regex's would be pretty simple.

Comment: @Rook that's what I was going to do, but I wanted to see if something was out there already.

Answer (score 2):

I have no out-of-the-box solution for you, but if you want to take the route of regular expressions, you can identify credit card numbers with the regular expression included in the [OWASP ESAPI validation properties](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/source/browse/trunk/src/main/resources/.esapi/validation.properties?r=557):

```
^(\\d{4}[- ]?){3}\\d{4}$
```

You have to take a closer look if it works for all cases you will run into. If the number is somehow malformed, the regular expression will fail of course.

A CVV2 number is just 3 or 4 digit number. You can also replace all of them with x's, but you will have a high rate of false positives. If the text you want to sanitize as some structure that helps you to find the credit card numbers and CVV2s, you can create something more elegant.

Comment: Yup, CVV2 is going to be more problematic. I don't know if there is going to be any structure to it. It looks like it's going to be some kind of arbitrary text. I'll see if I can figure something out. Thanks for the link to the OWASP docs!